# Cannot render Leaflet tilelayer

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, dust.js

I'm trying to use Leaflet to generate an interactive map. However I'm having some trouble rendering the tilelayer. I'm using dustjs to render the HTML, which is only giving me a blank map, like so:

[image: Blank map]

I initially tried to complete this using MapBox as per the [Quick Start](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/) guide. I believe I've got the correct access token,

```
    var mymap = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=XYZ', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
        maxZoom: 18,
        id: 'USERNAME.STYLEID',
        accessToken: 'XYZ'
    }).addTo(mymap);
```

I got my style id from the URL like this:

[image: Style id source]

I also tried using OSM in order to bypass any issues with getting the access token and project id, so I took this code from a tutorial I found:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [43.64701, -79.39425],
        zoom: 15
    });

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

But that also renders a blank map.

Here is the full code dump using OSM:

```js
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="../js/leaflet.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="onload()">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script>
        var map = L.map('map', {
            center: [43.64701, -79.39425],
            zoom: 15
        });

        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);
    </script>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance for any help. If you need more info let me know.

Comment: Make sure you div has non-zero size (both width and height) before you initialise leaflet component.

Comment: Can you double check that css files are loading properly?

Comment: @lonelyelk width and height comes from the stylesheet which is loaded before everything else.

Comment: @muzaffar [image](http://i.imgur.com/9bl7tBL.png)

Comment: @Jack .. I need you to confirm that external css files like leaflet.css is loading properly, would you please open the developer tool etc and check there if the css file has been added to page properly

Comment: @muzaffar [image](http://i.imgur.com/Bh15fae.png)

Comment: Please come here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131570/cannot-render-leaflet-tilelayer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the the parenthesis in the `tilelayer` are not working as they should. As the templates are compiled, therefore the dust compiler is likely ignoring the parameters in `{}`

Include a `*.js` file rather than inline-ing would work.